# instagram sharing no longer works?

Tags: ios, swift, instagram

It's almost 2020 and I can't find any recent articles on this. But is this information outdated now? com.instagram.exclusivegram doesn't seem to let instagram show up in the share sheet, while com.instagram.photo still works.

Here are the references:

https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed/

Comment: Use the extension `.igo` for the photo to show up with `com.instagram.exclusivegram`

Comment: Yes, I did that, because it's in the two references I linked.